# Image is disappearing when we add anchor tag in telerik editor on image

Tags: hyperlink, telerik, anchor, telerik-editor

When I want to add a anchor tag then my image is disappearing from the editor.
Here is the HTML `<a href="TempleteEditor.aspx?from=MenuPages.aspx&amp;pid=34441&amp;ln=nl"><img src="http://demo42.sitetogo.nl/uploads/1330/Projecten/project1_2.jpg" alt="Project 1" width="200px" height="150px" style="margin: 0px 0px 20px; float: left;" /></a></h1>`

And when I add anchor tag through the drop down then it will become disappear.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXG5G.png)